# Trying to detect an event for tracking in google analytics

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics

We have a Laravel app wherein we have the customer fill a form to book a request and when the form finishes if he is logged in then the data gets entered into the database using the Controller and other php code and then redirected to the dashboard but if he is not logged in then he has to login / register and then it does the data storage and then redirects to the dashboard.

the code for the ServiceController is :-

```
    public function requestEmergency(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->input();
        session(['homecare' => $data]);
        if (Auth::guest())
        {
            return Redirect::to('/register');
        } else
        {
            $this->requestServices("E");
            Session::flash('success_message', $this->statusmessage);

            return Redirect::to('request');
        }
    }
```

We are trying to track the successful completion of the request booking event but because of this login layer in between I don't know how to track this event of successful completion of the request so please assist.

If you need any more code then please lemme know

Answer (score 0):

I added query string parameters to the route like this

```
public function requestEmergency(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->input();
        session(['homecare' => $data]);
        if (Auth::guest())
        {
            return Redirect::to('/register');
        } else
        {
            $this->requestServices("E");
            Session::flash('success_message', $this->statusmessage);

            return Redirect::to('request?emergency=booked');
        }
    }
```

and then captured these parameters from my blade file using javascript

```
if (document.URL.indexOf('emergency=booked') != -1) {
  // google analytics code here
}
```

Hope this helps anybody